# is -Dfoobar the standard for adding definition to the compiler for all C++ compiler?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc

I am wondering if -Dfoobar the standard way for adding definition to the compiler for all the C++ compiler.

Comment: No.  For Visual C++, it's `/D`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Hyphens are also accepted (although the slash is more common).

Answer (score 2):

`-Dfoobar` works for all the compilers that have ever been used to compile Firefox, which is good enough for me. The Microsoft compilers also accept `/Dfoobar`, of course.